# Scaffolding with Microsoft.AspNet.Identity in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to create a new Controller using Scaffolding and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity but I get an error saying that 
`"IdentityUserLogin" has no key defined.`

I'm trying to create a relationship between a Clients table and the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity user's table.

The fields I use to build the relationship is `UserCreated`, `UserModified` and `UserAssigned`.

The model is:

```
[Table("Clients")]
public partial class Client
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Criado em")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-M-yyyy HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Alterado em")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-M-yyyy HH:mm}")]
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public virtual string UserCreated_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserCreated_Id")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser UserCreated { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public virtual string UserModified_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserModified_Id")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser UserModified { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public virtual string UserAssigned_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserAssigned_Id")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser UserAssigned { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Morada")]
    [MaxLength(512)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public int PostalCode { get; set; }
    public int PostalCodeExtension { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string PostalCodeCity { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fax")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Fax { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contribuinte")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string VAT { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be because it is how you defined `ApplicationUser`. I use the following implementation and it works perfect  -

```
public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{

}

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
{
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{

}
```

Then use it like this -

```
public class DomainEntity : .....
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

}
```

**EDIT**: User manager requires a second parameter, the key type. So change it like - this

```
 UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
```

and others -

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I use the MVC 5 Template and I don't have access to the UserLogin definition

Comment: Then just ignore it, add the required ones only. `IdentityUser` has multiple implementations.

Comment: I get the line: public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)  underlined under "manager"

Comment: Then you need to add the key parameter for type. Check the edit

Comment: Now I get the ApplicationDbContext underlined :S

Comment: I get the ApplicationRole underlined :S sorry

Comment: Its the same, basically you have to mention the `<int>`. key type parameter in all you derived classes. Just continue doing it and you will okay.

Comment: I'm a bit lost in this part, I don't have the class ApplicationRole declared, should I create it?

Comment: My one looks like this - `ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int, ApplicationUserRole>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96938/discussion-between-patrick-and-brainless-coder).